# Docker stuck in starting

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-volume

I need to write a Makefile that launches a docker-compose.yml file, which builds and runs nginx, WordPress, and MariaDB images for which I have written my own Dockerfiles. Everything works fine, but when I link the created volumes to the corresponding images, it doesn't work and it remains in the 'creating' state during launch.

I tried creating a volume without any parameters, and it works. However, when I provide a complete path, it deletes the contents of the directory on the image side and mounts an empty directory in its place. And when I use `driver_opts: o: bind type: none` and `device: ${HOME}/data/..`, it gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: Please share more details, like the docker-compose.yml, such that others can reproduce the problem